# How can I use more than one query in Node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

So I am not sure how node-pg works but I have been trying to make it work by looking around, trying things and reading the documentation for a while now. What I want to achieve is to be able to send multiple queries at different times but it always throws errors after i send the first one if I dare coding a second one in. This question has been asked multiple times online but I dont see any helpful answers. I can use pooling if its necessary (that had issues too).

**What works now:** (Its on heroku so i have to use process.env.DATABASE_URL)

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
ssl: {
rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
client.connect()

client

.query('SELECT * FROM test WHERE....')
.then(results => {
console.log(results);
}

.catch(err => {
console.log(err.stack)
 })
```

**What I 'm trying to do:**

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
ssl: {
rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
client.connect()

client

.query('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE....')
.then(results => {
console.log("FIRST RESULTS: "results);
}

.catch(err => {
console.log(err.stack)
 })

.query('SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE....')
.then(results => {
console.log("SECOND RESULTS: "results);
}

.catch(err => {
console.log(err.stack)
 })
```

Comment: I tried multiple things so i got multiple different errors. I was probably not doing it right but I cant find any example online with more than one query thats why i came here. While using pooling, when i used specific clients like this example: https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling the error was ''client.query(...).then(...).query is not a function'' on the second query, while without clients its similarly: "TypeError: pool.query(...).then(...).catch(...).query is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `.query`, a Promise is returned, and Promises don't have `.query` methods - all you can do with the Promise is call `.then` or `.catch` on it (or `.finally`, sometimes).

If you want to make a new query after the old finishes, call `client.query` inside a `.then`:

```
client
  .query('SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE....')
  .then(results => {
      console.log("FIRST RESULTS: " + results);
    })
    .then(() => client.query('SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE....'))
    .then(results => {
      console.log("SECOND RESULTS: " + results);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // better to handle errors at the end, probably
      console.log(err.stack)
    })
```

If the second query depends on the first's result, consider using an `async` function instead, to make the code flatter and more readable.

If the second query *doesn't* depend on the first's result, consider using `Promise.all` instead, so that both queries can be made at once, rather than having to wait for the first to finish first.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, that works. That answers my question so I'm accepting it but Im not sure what i should do if i need more queries later in a different block of code. Can I just call a function that includes the same process again? "Client.query(..).then(..)" because when i tried that i got yet another error. It works fine in consecutive .THENs but I do not know what to do in that other instance. If you are willing to help more I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Any time you have more queries to run, return them inside `.then`s so that the next `.then` can deal with their resolve values. If you want to run two queries at once, then do `return Promise.all([client.query(...), client.query(..)])` and `.then(([result1, result2]) => { /* do stuff with result1 and result2 */`

Comment: Thank you, i think i figured it all out with your help. Hopefully last question, when should i use client.end()?? If i understand it right once i use it then i can not send any more queries again not even reopen it somehow right?

Comment: I think you'd call it once you're finished, like after a `finally`. `.catch(...).finally(() => { client.end(); });`